# Checking package versions in a miniconda environment

Tags: python-3.6, conda, virtual-environment

I hava a conda environment called test and a requirements file-requirements.txt.

What i need to achieve is that i need to check the versions of different packages against those in requirements.txt and display which are upto date and which are not.

I need to write a python script for the task. For eg: if requirements.txt has django==2.0.6, i have to check against the installed version of django in the test environment and display accordingly.

The steps that i thought are :

1. Activating the environment inside script
2. running "conda list" command and saving all the packages along with their versions in a map as key-value pairs
3. matching against the requirements.txt

How to activate the environment inside a python script using "conda activate test" and run the command "conda list"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conda list` accepts the argument `-n` to specify an environment like this:

```
conda list -n test
```

so no need to activate the conda env

Comment: But since conda is a shell primitive and not a command, running it via subprocess.popen is a problem. how to run that command inside a python script and store the output?